# How to use a custom method of a FilterInputStream inside another FilterInputStream

Tags: java, stream, inputstream

I have two streams extending the FilterInputStream class. A is reading doubles from the stream and B shall take those doubles and apply a random noise on them. The question is about how to implement the second stream correctly, so B has access to the custom function of A returning doubles. The chaining shall be as follows:

Source ----> A ----> double ----> B ----> doubles with noise

Best Regards, Turakar

Comment: Why? Why the two `FilterInputStreams`? Why not combine them? Have you considered `DataInputStream`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `FilteredInputStream` seems to be not very suitable for your problem as `InputStream` represents a sequence of bytes, but what you need is the sequence of `double` numbers. One possible alternative is to implement the `Iterator` interface instead. Thus `A` would become:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoubleIterator implements Iterator<Double> {
    private Scanner scanner;

    public DoubleIterator(InputStream is) {
        scanner = new Scanner(is);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return scanner.hasNextDouble();
    }

    @Override
    public Double next() {
        return scanner.nextDouble();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

And `B` would become

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;

public class NoiseIterator implements Iterator<Double> {
    Random r = new Random();
    private Iterator<Double> source;

    public NoiseIterator(Iterator<Double> source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return source.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public Double next() {
        return source.next()+r.nextGaussian();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

These classes can be used in the following manner:

```
String s = "1 56 123 30 0";

Iterator<Double> it = new DoubleIterator(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes()));
while(it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
it = new NoiseIterator(new DoubleIterator(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes())));
while(it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Typical output:

```
1.0
56.0
123.0
30.0
0.0
-0.011797617285828732
55.71721599815757
123.33995522117877
29.16152453760448
-0.9614750776766922
```